# How to make a cart products length globally to use anywhere In Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce project and I have added the cart products length in the cart page but I want to use the cart product length in each page of the product. So, how I can make it globally.

This is my **cart.ts**:

```
import { CheckoutPage } from './../checkout/checkout';
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from "../../providers/cart/cart";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-cart',
  templateUrl: 'cart.html',
})
export class CartPage {
 cartItems: any[] = [];
 totalAmount: number = 0;
 isCartItemLoaded: boolean = false;
 isEmptyCart: boolean = true;
 ifSize: boolean = true;
 productCount: number = 1;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(cartItems.length);
  }
}
```

I want to `cartItems.length` globally, So that I can use it in each page. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **RxJs** **Subject** here:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-k2nlv6)

cart.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  subject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }
  public setCart(cart: any) {
    this.subject.next({ cart: cart });
  }
  public getCart(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

page1.component.ts(adding carts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartService } from '../../app/cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class Page1 {
  cartItems: Array<any> = [];
  cartLength: number;
  constructor(public cart: CartService, public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  addCart(cartDetails) {
    this.cartItems.push(cartDetails);
    this.cart.setCart(this.cartItems);
  }
}
```

page2.component.ts(getting carts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartService } from '../../app/cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class Page2 {
  cartLength: number;
  constructor(private cart: CartService, public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.cart.getCart().subscribe(data => {
      this.cartLength = data.cart.length;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: In case this is the correct answer, should the OP add the ngOnDestroy to finish the lifecycle of the observable to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Where to create cart.service.ts, like what will the file location. In providers or in app folder?

Comment: Can I also use store for this?

Comment: please go to demo url i have given .

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: But there is one problem that whenever I open the app it initially set to zero and when I add the product, it takes the product length.